# Nextjs not Rendering Images Stored in Public Folder in Production Only

Tags: next.js

I'm building a personal website with Nextjs and I'm encountering a weird issue with the Public folder. Per the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving), static images are to be put in the Public folder. This works perfectly for all images in my local development mode. However, as soon as I push this to production with Vercel, some images would fail to render (showing broken image). I noticed it seems to load jpg images fine but not png / svg. I don't use next-images module and just use a simple  tag.

My file structure (simplified) is:

- public

  - static

    - Melbourne.jpg
    - avatar.png
- pages

  - index.jsx

In my index.jsx (also super simplied)

```
function Homepage({ data }) {
    
    return (
        <motion.div id='home' initial='initial' animate='enter' exit='exit'>
            <section
                id='intro'
                className='bg-dark flex content-center flex-wrap p-40 justify-center text-center min-h-screen w-screen'>
                <div className='flex flex-col justify-center'>
                    <motion.img
                        src='/static/avatar.png' <-- Works in Dev but not Prod
                        className='flex mx-auto rounded-full h-32 w-32'
                        variants={{
                            initial: { opacity: 0 },
                            enter: {
                                opacity: 1,
                                transition: {
                                    ease: 'easeIn',
                                    duration: 0.5,
                                    delay: 0.75,
                                },
                            },
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id='about' className='bg-light w-screen p-10'>
                <div className='h-2 border-t-4 border-dark w-10/12 flex flex-column mx-auto mt-12' />
                <div className='w-1/3 mx-auto relative bottom-12 bg-light'>
                    <h1 className='font-header text-center'>About Me</h1>
                </div>
                <div className='flex mx-auto mb-8 w-11/12 md:w-3/4 grid grid-cols-3 gap-6 lg:grid-cols-3'>
                    <div className='py-8 col-span-2'>
                        Some text here
                    </div>
                    <div className=''>
                        <img
                            className='rounded-full w-full h-full'
                            src='/static/Melbourne.jpg' <-- Works in Dev & Prod
                            alt='melbourne-skyline'
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </section>
            
        </motion.div>
    );
}

export default Homepage;
```

Please ignore any possible syntax error, everything works on my end and I deleted a lot of things to simplify this. The only issue I'm encountering is the  tag.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try without the transitions?

Comment: Yeah I did. Still didn't work in production. Both with and without transition works perfectly in the local development mode though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebuild [ `npm run build` ] the project after adding new assets, then commit the changes.